# Vertical align two images using display: table-cell

Tags: css, layout

I want to vertical two images with CSS' display: table-cell, but seems not work even I've specify the height

```
<div style='display: table;height:500px'>
    <div style=' display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;'>
        <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Intel-logo.svg/200px-Intel-logo.svg.png' />
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Intel-logo.svg/500px-Intel-logo.svg.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/33KYS/

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `vertical-align` property to image too!

```
img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/33KYS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

When working only with images, you don't need to wrap inside a `table` and `table-cell`. A vertical align on the image itself also works.

```
.img { vertical-align: middle; }

<div>
        <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Intel-logo.svg/200px-Intel-logo.svg.png' />
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Intel-logo.svg/500px-Intel-logo.svg.png" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/33KYS/2/